# How to forward search and reverse search for a character in a HTML document without using TextRange API in IE11/Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We have a two column HTML layout. I want to implement forward search and backward search for a particular character in HTML, Like the "$" character in IE11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5PcL.jpg)

Earlier in IE10 we used to use TextRange API of IE to do it, the way we used to handle it was, if we have cursor position in first "$" character, we used to create two ranges range1, range2. range1 would be current selection range and range2 would be on entire document. Then we would use setEndPointAPI to TextRange to set start of range2 same as range1 and end of range1 same as range2. This enables us to find the text in forward direction using the TextRange's findText API, and once the character is found I have to select that character and vice versa for reverse search.

Now that Textrange has been deprecated starting from IE11, I tried to use the same using Range but since the APIs are not readily available as in TextRange API, is there any other way to mimic the same functionality?

corresponding HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  <div>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Test 1</span>
    <p>Some te$xt..</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Test 2</span>
    <p>Some te$xt..</p>
    <div>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  <div>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Test 3</span>
    <p>Some t$ext..</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Test 4</span>
    <p>Some t$ext..</p>
    <div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the JavaScript String method to find the related characters and highlight the selected text. Please refer to the following sample code ([online sample](http://jsfiddle.net/k2uj69Ls/)):

CSS style:

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .highlight {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var currentindex = -1; //default status
    var items = [];
    var field; 
    function Init() {
        items = [];
        field = document.getElementById("findField").value;
        var plist = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
        for (var i = 0; i < plist.length; i++) {
            if (plist[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(field) > -1) {
                items.push(plist[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function textchange() {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].innerHTML = items[i].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, "");
        }
        currentindex = -1;
    }
    function FindNext() {
        Init();
        if (items.length > 0) { 
            if (currentindex == items.length-1) {
                items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, "");
                currentindex = 0;
                items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(field, "<span class='highlight'>" + field + "</span>");
            }
            else { 

                if (currentindex != -1) 
                    items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, ""); //click the Forward button at the first time
                currentindex++;
                items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(field, "<span class='highlight'>" + field + "</span>");
            }   
        }
        else {
            alert("the value was not found");
        }
    }

    function FindPrevious() {
        Init();
        if (items.length > 0) {
            if (currentindex == -1) { 
                // click the previous button at the first time.
                currentindex = items.length - 1;
                items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(field, "<span class='highlight'>" + field + "</span>");
            }
            else {
                if (currentindex == 0) {
                    items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, "");
                    currentindex = items.length - 1;
                    items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(field, "<span class='highlight'>" + field + "</span>");
                }
                else { 
                    items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g, "");
                    currentindex--;
                    items[currentindex].innerHTML = items[currentindex].innerHTML.replace(field, "<span class='highlight'>" + field + "</span>");
                }
            }           
            //console.log(currentindex);
        }
        else {
            alert("the value was not found");
        }
    }
</script
```

Then, the output as below:

[image]